# Changing orientation of android app at runtime

Tags: java, android, orientation

Is it possible to change screen orientation of an app programatically if it is fixed in androidmanifest.Xml.I have fixe portrait mode in AndroidManifest But in a particular case i want to change orientation to landscape and when it goes out of that case it must again change to portrait mode

Comment: Please use punctuation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and for portrait:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: which file i need to  import to use this

Comment: import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;